# "Would have" or "would had" - use of tenses in a sentence

Tags: tense

Are the tenses in this sentence correct?

> If you **would have** worked hard you would not have had to suffer this much.

or should this be correct?

> If you **would had** worked hard you would not have had to suffer this much.

I am not sure whether I should use *have* or *had* following *would*.

Comment: A simple search for "would have vs would had" gives many results. If you did this, what did you find?

Comment: We generally don't allow "proofreading" questions.  Please add more detail what about this grammar you find confusing or difficult, so that other people can benefit from the answer.

Comment: @Andrew I don't think this is a proofreading question. There's a specific point the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Andrew Generally, you can infer this from the singular part of the sentences that are different... which is why this sort of question *generally* isn't considered proofreading... that being said, the user needs to explain more and show some basic research.

Comment: Modals (like _would_, _can_, _might_, _may_) are always followed by the base form of the next verb, whether it is a full verb or an auxiliary. So _would had_ is never grammatical.

Answer (score 7):

Both of your suggested sentences are incorrect. You want to talk about a hypothetical situation: to do this, for most sentences you simply backshift the tense, in the same way that you would for reported speech. As you will see from [this link](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm), simple past goes to past perfect:

> you worked hard - *simple past: a past action*
>  
>   you had worked hard - *past perfect: backshifted for a hypothetical situation*

Plug that into the sentence, and you get:

> If you had worked hard, you would not have had to suffer this much.

You only use **would** for hypothetical situations when you need the past of **will**.

> I will meet you at the airport
>   I would meet you at the airport if I had a car.

Comment: In colloquial English (AmE at least) we often hear this pattern: "If you woulda told me earlier, I coulda done something about it." meaning, "Had you seen fit to tell me earlier, I could have done something about it."

Answer (score -1):

The first is correct: "If you ***would*** have worked, . . . "

Why? . . . because the tense is future perfective; and, only the first part of the verbal form changes in such a construction.

And, by the way, I think, it should properly be this: "If you would have worked hard, you would not have had to ***have*** suffer***ed*** this much."

Comment: The construction you are proffering (...have had to have suffered...) seems to be rare and interesting from a grammatical point of view. In what areas of the English speaking world can it be encountered?

Answer (score -3):

**"Would have"** is a modal verb that describes an unreal condition in the past. Usually, **would have** suggests a bad feeling about the past. *Could have*, *would have*, and *should have* are sometimes called **“modals of lost opportunities”**

Both your sentences are incorrect *(never use **has** or **had** to form a past modal)*:

- When talking about something that **didn’t happen in the past**, many English speakers use the **conditional perfect** *(if I would have done)* when they should be using the **past perfect** *(if I had done)* instead. The **conditional perfect** can only go in the **then clause** – it is grammatically incorrect to use the **conditional perfect** in the **if clause**:
- The same mistake occurs with the verb **wish**. You can’t use the **conditional perfect** when **wishing something had happened**. Again, you need the **past perfect**.
- You can always reverse conditional sentences.

---

The correct structure in your example should be:

- If you had worked hard, you would not have had to suffer this much.

If **would have** comes first, there should be no comma.

- You would not have had to suffer this much if you had worked hard.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this answer has received downvotes? To me it seems correct.